# BASH choosing and counting distinct based on two column

Tags: bash, csv, awk, count, distinct

Hey guys so i got this dummy data:

```
115,IROM,1
125,FOLCOM,1
135,SE,1
111,ATLUZ,1
121,ATLUZ,2
121,ATLUZ,2
142,ATLUZ,2
142,ATLUZ,2
144,BLIZZARC,1
166,STEAD,3
166,STEAD,3
166,STEAD,3
168,BANDOI,1
179,FOX,1
199,C4,2
199,C4,2
```

Desired output:

```
IROM,1
FOLCOM,1
SE,1
ATLUZ,3
BLIZZARC,1
STEAD,1
BANDOI,1
FOX,1
C4,1
```

which comes from counting the distinct game id (the 115,125,etc). so for example the

```
111,ATLUZ,1
121,ATLUZ,2
121,ATLUZ,2
142,ATLUZ,2
142,ATLUZ,2
```

Will be

```
ATLUZ,3
```

Since it have 3 distinct game id

I tried using

```
cut -d',' -f 2 game.csv|uniq -c
```

Where i got the following output

```
  1 IROM
  1 FOLCOM
  1 SE
  5 ATLUZ
  1 BLIZZARC COMP
  3 STEAD
  1 BANDOI
  1 FOX
  2 C4
```

How do i fix this ? using bash ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before executing the `cut` command, do a `uniq`. This will remove the redundant lines and then you follow your command, i.e. apply `cut` to extract `2` field and do `uniq -c` to count character

```
uniq game.csv | cut -d',' -f 2 | uniq -c
```

Comment: thanks for that, out of curiousity if you don't mind i have another question how do you sort in awk so that it sort dot(.) first ? i tried sort but dot doesn't appear first ?

Comment: @user3646742. not sorting but I have made logic by which your output will be same as Input_file's sequence. Kindly try it out once and let me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yeah both of solution work thanks, its just a short different question i asked in the comment

Comment: Add `121,ATLUZ,1` and this won't work! It removes only exact duplicates...

Comment: @PesaThe I agree but based on filer input file, that seems to be the case.

Comment: If you make that first command `sort -u` instead of `uniq` then it'll work even if the original file wasn't sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following too in a single `awk`.

```
awk -F, '
!a[$1,$2,$3]++{
  b[$1,$2,$3]++
}
!f[$2]++{
  g[++count]=$2
}
END{
  for(i in b){
    split(i,array,",")
    c[array[2]]++
  }
  for(q=1;q<=count;q++){
    print c[g[q]],g[q]
  }
}' SUBSEP=","  Input_file
```

It will give the order of output same as Input_file's 2nd field occurrence as follows.

```
1 IROM
1 FOLCOM
1 SE
3 ATLUZ
1 BLIZZARC
1 STEAD
1 BANDOI
1 FOX
1 C4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html):

```
datamash -t, --sort --group 2 countunique 1 < input
```

Using [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk -F, '!a[$1,$2]++{b[$2]++}END{for(i in b)print i FS b[i]}' input
```

Using [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html), [`cut`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html), [`uniq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html):

```
sort -u -t, -k2,2 -k1,1 input | cut -d, -f2 | uniq -c
```

---

**Test run:**

```
$ cat input
111,ATLUZ,1
121,ATLUZ,1
121,ATLUZ,2
142,ATLUZ,2
115,IROM,1
142,ATLUZ,2
$ datamash -t, --sort --group 2 countunique 1 < input
ATLUZ,3    
IROM,1
```

As you can see, `121,ATLUZ,1` and `121,ATLUZ,2` are correctly considered to be just one `game ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant, but you may use awk as well. If it is not granted that the same ID+NAME combos will always come consecutively, you have to count each by reading the whole file before output:

```
awk -F, '{c[$1,$2]+=1}END{for (ck in c){split(ck,ca,SUBSEP); print ca[2];g[ca[2]]+=1}for(gk in g){print gk,g[gk]}}' game.csv
```

This will count first every [COL1,COL2] pairs then for each COL2 it counts how many distinct [COL1,COL2] pairs are nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

This also does the trick. The only thing is that your output is not sorted.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "," }{ a[$2 FS $1] }END{ for ( i in a ){ split(i, b, "," ); c[b[1]]++ } for ( i in c ) print i, c[i] }' yourfile
```

Output:

```
BANDOI,1
C4,1
STEAD,1
BLIZZARC,1
FOLCOM,1
ATLUZ,3
SE,1
IROM,1
FOX,1
```